# Else Part in PHP not printing

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I am trying to execute a simple program in PHP with Mysql using IF ELSE Condition

My code is executing IF part but not Else

Please Help me
 and here is my code

```
<?PHP


$userInputEntities = htmlentities($userInput);
echo $userInputEntities;

$username = "admin";
$password = "1234565";
$database = "tele";
$server = "localhost";
$db     = new PDO (
    "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", 
    "$username", 
    "$password");
$id     = $_REQUEST['cid'];
if ($db) {
    $SQL = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = :id");
    $SQL -> execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    while ($row = $SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if ($id=="$row[uid]") {
            echo "Welcome";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry You Have not registered with our service";
        }
    }
}
```

& 
My Database table is 'user'

```
  uid           name
   1            Manoj
   2            pranay   only two rows i have in table
```

If user input availble in table then it should print if part and if user not found then it should print else part
Please Help me, Thankyou

Here If part is printing when IF condition satisfies but not printing else part when If condition fails

Comment: means... satisfying if($id=="$row[uid]") condition

Comment: I mean if condition fails then it should print else part but it is not printing @mhasan

Comment: @Aryan - if condition is fails then we cant stop else part here.. surely execute. if not check whether while loop is working or not???

Comment: if you are expecting one row or an empty return, you should not use while loop. look at @raina77ow answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole `while` block won't be executed if your query returns empty set (in case when there's no user in DB with the given `id`). So placing `else` in this block is meaningless: if `while` body is entered, `$id` will ALWAYS be equal to `$row['uid']` - it's the condition set in `WHERE` clause, remember.

You need to check the row count instead, and branch your code based on that, replacing the whole `while` block with something like this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = :id");
$sql->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
if ($sql->rowCount()) { 
  echo "Welcome";
}
else {
  echo "Sorry, you Have not registered with our service";
}
```

The alternative is changing the query (`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`) so it will return the count instead of the whole row, and checking its value against 0.

Comment: using this also not printing the else part @raina77ow :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

```
$_REQUEST['cid']
```

Is resolving as the same as:

```
"$row[uid]"
```

For every call, which means the else condition (the first doesn't equal the second) is never met.

In situations like these I like to echo the value of the variables when I'm not sure what their values are or if I want to compare them to see if my code is working as expected. That way you can see explicitly what's being compared for the two variables.